# If loop that is adding new values as a whole column instead of one row in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and trying to run an if loop so that if the probability given is an even number, I would add 0.1 to that number and in a new column "new_probability". However, when I run that if loop, it adds the new value as a column name with each original probability as each row.

```
data['New_Probability'] = data['Probability']
data.loc[data['Probability'] * 10 % 2 == 0, data['New_Probability']] = (data['Probability'] + .1)
```

This is preventing the loop from running correctly and only changing the correct probability values. Is there a better/easier way to loop this or do I just have something out of place?

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample dataframe and an expected output?

Comment: `However, when I run that if loop, it adds the new value as a column name with each original probability as each row.` How looks your loop?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to do it, for example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Probability':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]})
```

You can use the boolean you have:

```
data['Probability'] * 10 % 2 == 0

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: Probability, dtype: bool
```

We multiply this by 0.1, False would be 0 and True would be 1, so it gives you the expected output in the end:

```
data['New_Probability'] = data['Probability'] \
+ 0.1 *(data['Probability'] * 10 % 2 == 0)


   Probability  New_Probability
0          0.1              0.1
1          0.2              0.3
2          0.3              0.3
3          0.4              0.5
```